# Spring boot graphite network information

Tags: spring-boot, grafana, graphite, micrometer

I am setting up graphite / grafana for my spring boot application. I am trying to find how to get network information like bytes in / out (network stats). Can someone tell me how I could derive this information? I am using tomcat as boot server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See meter name `tomcat.global.received` and `tomcat.global.sent` which come from Tomcat JMX Bean `GlobalRequestProcessor`'s `bytesReceived` and `bytesSent` attributes respectively.

See also [the relevant part of code in Micrometer](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/master/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/tomcat/TomcatMetrics.java#L180-L190).